# Замыкание в js (простой пример)

Tags: javascript, замыкания

Имеется следующий код:

```js
function foo() {
    var count = 0;
    return function foo2() {
        count++;
        console.log(count);
    }
}
var d = foo();
d();
d();
d();
```

Пример простого замыкания.
Вопрос: почему, для того, чтобы работал код нужно создавать переменную и помещать туда вызов функции? Почему если вызвать функции напрямую foo(); (без переменной), то не работает?

Comment: foo() возвращает вложенную  функцию, которая в последствии вызывается

Comment: тогда можно написать foo()();  , но так тоже не работает

Comment: Вам уже ответили

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто, не происходит вызов функции... Без переменной правильной будет такая конструкция

```
function foo() {
    var count = 0;
    return function foo2() {
        count++;
        console.log(count);
    }
}
foo()() // 1
foo()() // 1
foo()() // 1
```

Проблема в том, что каждый вызов функции foo создает новую переменную count. Если count будет объявлена вне функции или частью её прототипа, то инкремент будет происходить корректно

```
function foo() {
    foo.prototype.count=foo.prototype.count|0;
    return function foo2() {
        foo.prototype.count++;
        console.log(foo.prototype.count);
    }
}
foo()() // 1
foo()() // 2
foo()() // 3
```

Comment: То есть функция не сохраняет свое состояние, а при каждом вызове срабатывает по новой? А при создании нами переменной и помещении туда вызова функции она сохраняет состояние в этой переменной... Выходит так?

Comment: @Craft1k, При каждом вызове foo - это именно НОВАЯ функция. В вашем случае - мы вызываем НОВУЮ уже повторно(её вернула foo), а во втором моём - модифицируется основа самой функции

Comment: @ТрипольскийПётр я не понял вот эту часть ?Зачем тут побитовый оператор?`foo.prototype.count=foo.prototype.count|0;`

Comment: @Demon__ANT по всей видимости это было ||

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ты уверен?

Comment: @Demon__ANT в целом смысл в том что при первом вызове, когда count еще нет присвоить туда 0, “или” в этом случае на мой взгляд понятнее, чем сайд эффект от побитового или и undefined

Comment: @StrangerintheQ благодарю